# Keycloak set permissions based on method [GET, POST, PATCH]

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to set view and update permissions to resources in my project; if a user has role `x` then they can only view this resource, if they have role `y` then they can view and update the same resource.

What I've done so far is created a resource and defined 2 scopes one for view and the other for update. But, what I can't figure out is how to define the method (`GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`).

Here's my `SecurityConfig.java`

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KeycloakSpringBootProperties.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        final SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
        final KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(this.keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public AccessToken accessToken() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
            return ((KeycloakPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal()).getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
        } else {
            return new AccessToken();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ensures the correct registration of KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver when Keycloaks AutoConfiguration
     * is explicitly turned off in application.yml {@code keycloak.enabled: false}.
     */
    @Configuration
    static class CustomKeycloakBaseSpringBootConfiguration extends KeycloakBaseSpringBootConfiguration {
    }
}
```

`application.yml`

```
keycloak:
  enabled: false
  realm: phelix
  auth-server-url: URL
  ssl-required: none
  resource: CLIENT
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  bearer-only: true
  cors: true
  policy-enforcer-config:
    enforcement-mode: PERMISSIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

Add request matcher for method type:

```
 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasAnyRole("x", "y")
 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").hasRole("y")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Pawel.S., but unfortunately that didn't work. Also, by doing so we're defining the same permission twice? Once in Keycloak Admin UI and the other in the code with `.antMatchers()`?

Comment: Yes, you have to define all roles twice. In a keycloak you can define that role as a Realm Role or a Client Role, but do not forget about assigning that role to a user.
You have enabled 'EnableGlobalMethodSecurity', is your controller additionally protected by annotations? Like that:

Comment: In that case there's no need to define Resources, Scopes, Policies and Permissions on Keycloak since we're putting the logic with `antMatchers`, correct?

Comment: I think there are two different approaches:
1. Define all in Spring Boot app;
2. use [Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/) in Keycloak

It depends on capabilities of resource server.